# Error while compiling in Qt (Ubuntu)

Tags: qt4, ubuntu-9.04

I am getting the following error while compiling a sample program in Qt 4.5 in Ubuntu OS.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, I installed the library libqt4-dev by typing the command

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. `gthread` is part of `libglib` nowadays.

My solutions was to

```
aptitude install libglib2.0-dev libglibmm-2.4-dev
```

which is about a ton fewer packages than what `libqt4-dev` with friends pulled in.